# Protractor memory error

Tags: memory, html-table, protractor

I am using the following call

```
expect(element(by.css('MyTableCssIdentifier')).element(by.cssContainingText("td", RowName)).getText()).toEqual(RowValue, ' Row value does not match expected')
```

it is giving the following error on a table with 250+ entries in it. I a getting the following error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

It does not appear I can break the table down further (i.e. no other identifier to only use half of the table at a time or some such). I am able to return just the entire table without any issues. I have also tried wrapping in a function with the filter option:

```
    this.getElementFromTable = function(RowName) {
    return element.all(by.repeater('MyRepeaterID')).filter(function (row) {
        return row.$$('td').get(1).getText().then(function (rowName) {
            return rowName == RowName;
        });
    }).then(function (rows) {
        try {
            return rows[0].getText().then(function (RowValue) {
                return RowValue;
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            return Error(' element not found ')
        }
    });
};
```

This also seems to give me the same allocation error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using `jasmine1`? If yes, please upgrade to `jasmine2` and try again.

Comment: Jasmine2 seems to have fixed the memory issue, but performance is really slow. On the order of three minutes to find and return one item in the table. I see in the terminal window the web driver churning away looking for it. Can I turn off that logging to see if that is what's slowing it down?

Comment: Thought I should add MacBook Pro specs:  
  Processor Name:  Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 2.8 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory: 16 GB

Comment: What if you would make it in one go: `element(by.cssContainingText('MyTableCssIdentifier td', RowName)).getText()`?